# Nest JS cannot resolve dependencies in the service

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have created a core module which has a service within it.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';


@Module({
  providers:[{ provide: CacheService, useValue: new CacheService()}],
  exports:[{ provide: CacheService, useValue: new CacheService()}]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

I have imported the `CoreModule` in the `AppModule`.

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
        CoreModule,
        offerModule
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

There is a offer module imported in the `AppModule`. When I am trying to inject the `CacheService` in the checkmodule, it is throwing the error below.

```
2019-02-05 13:40:25 [error]:    Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the OfferService (OfferRepository, ?, Connection, AppLogger). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the OfferModule context.
    at Injector.lookupComponentInExports (C:\Project Workspace\ts-sharing\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:144:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project Workspace\ts-sharing\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:157:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
 1: v8::internal::compiler::Type::Negative31
 2: v8::internal::wasm::SignatureMap::Find
 3: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor
 4: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor
 5: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor
 6: 0000023CE08843C1
```

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: As another suggestion there's no reason to structure your providers and exports like this. You don't gain anything by explicitly doing the provide/useValue you could just `CacheService` and Nest will instantiate it for you automatically

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the `CoreModule` in your `OfferModule` as well, so that it is available for its providers.

---

If you want your `CoreModule` to be available globally, you can make it a [global module](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) with the `@Global` decorator. With it, the module has to be imported only once (e.g. in the `AppModule`) and will then be available in all modules.

```
@Global()
@Module({
  providers:[CacheService],
  exports:[CacheService],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```